# adding more fields to CreateUserWizard

Tags: visual-studio-2010

is there an easy way to add more fileds to the CreateUserWizard control?

I'd like to add 5 more fields to the existing fields.

Answer (score 0):

Add new step for your wizard and put into additional fields. To store new fields use Profile.

More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178342.aspx).

EDIT: for storing information of additional fields in your custom wizard step you can use asp.net profile. For example, like [this](http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/9/adding-custom-profile-fields.aspx).

About ASP.NET Profile: physically Profile stores data in membership DB in table with name: aspnet_profile - one row for each user (one to one). All your predefined properties for profile in web.config will store data in one string field of this table with separator. So you don't need to worry about storing this information - use api (profileObj.Save();) and asp.net does it for you. [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/18/427754.aspx)

Notice - avoid to store big size of data in the Profile

Comment: Hi Breez.. Thanks for the answer. I checked the site. It is allowing me to add a new control. But it is appending the value to an existing field. How do i save the information in a new field? for xample. i want obtain the address, city, state information from the as part of the registration process.

Comment: Hi Breez. Thanks for the edit. The link talks about Profile. How do i store the profile information along with the registration information in the db?